# JUnit exception handling not working

Tags: java, maven, junit, exception

I'm new to unit testing and I'm trying to learn JUnit. Handling exceptions in tests is not working in my project. Here is my class:

```
public class Things {

  private int amount;
  private int[] weights;
  private int[] values;

  public Things(int amount, int[] weights, int[] values){
    this.amount = amount;
    if (amount!=weights.length || amount != values.length){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount of things different than weights or values length");
    }
    this.weights=weights;
    this.values=values;
  }
}
```

and Test class:

```
public class ThingsTest {

@Test
public void testThingsConstructorIllegalArgumentsException(){
    boolean exceptionThrown = false;
    try{
        Things thingsBadParams = new Things(5, new int[]{4,3,2}, new int[]{7,8});
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        exceptionThrown = true;
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(exceptionThrown);
}
}
```

I know that maybe this isn't the best way to handle exception, but that's not the point. I've tried probably every solution (with @Rule, @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class) and still every time the test is failing, there is a red bar and description below it:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Amount of things different than weights or values length

at pl.dsdev.Things.<init>(Things.java:14)
at ThingsTest.<init>(ThingsTest.java:11)
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2017, Maven and JUnit 4.12. What should I do to make test successful?

Comment: The stack trace shows that you're not executing the code you posted. The exception is thrown from the ThingsTest constructor. And there is no constructor in the posted code. Show us your **actual** code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rewrite you tests as:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testThingsConstructorIllegalArgumentsException(){
    Things thingsBadParams = new Things(5, new int[]{4,3,2}, new int[]{7,8});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, JB Nizet helped me find my mistake, I've created object

```
Things things = new Things(5, new int[]{3,2,5,1,3,7},new int[]{2,7,1,2,4,5});
```

outside the testing method, so every time this line thrown an exception, because there is 6 elements, not 5. Thank you guys :)